# C++ ShellExecute special characters

Tags: c++, shell, cmd

How can I run this command from ShellExecute?

With windows cmd, I use this line and works perfect:

```
    C:\backup.exe -daily %date%
```

that results:

```
    C:\backup.exe -daily 05/19/2016
```

But in C ++ the interpreter does not work with %.
It results:

```
    C:\backup.exe -daily %date%
```

How can I solve this problem?

```
    ShellExecute(NULL, NULL,
    "C:\\backup.exe",
    "-daily %date%",
    NULL,
    SW_HIDE
    );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `cmd.exe /C backup.exe ...` to let `cmd` take care of the variable substitution.

Comment: Call `ShellExecute` as before: `cmd.exe` goes as the executable `lpFile`, everything else becomes the parameter string `lpParameters`.